# F# LazyList -> IList

Tags: f#, lazylist

I'm creating a module that will be used by C# code, so I would rather not return the `LazyList<>` directly. If I did, the C# would have to reference the `FSharp.PowerPack`, which seems strange.

So I would rather return a `IList<>`, but when I try to do something like:

```
let x = LazyList.ofSeq {0..10}
let y = x :> IList<int32>
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
The type 'LazyList<int> is not compatible with the type 'IList<int>'
```

This leads me to believe that `LazyList<>` does NOT `implement` `IList<>`. Is this true?

What am I missing?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9201402/2145211) could be helpful

Comment: `IList<_>` exposes things like `Count` which only make sense if the list is fully constructed, so it makes sense that `LazyList<_>` doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: @kvb: I was taking DoctorJones (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689986/lazylistt-vs-system-lazylistt-in-asp-net-mvc-2/2690307#2690307) at his word a bit... But it definately makes sense that it wouldn't be able to do most of the functionality from `IList<>`

Comment: I think that's actually in reference to a different `LazyList<_>` class, not F#'s.

Comment: There is `LazyList` in the ExtCore library, which also does *not* implement `IList` (https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/Collections.LazyList.fs), but I think it would be a reasonable addition, so perhaps you could submit a pull request and use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true, LazyList does not implement the IList interface. It implements IEnumerable though.

```
[<Sealed>]
type LazyList<'T> =
   interface IEnumerable<'T>
   interface System.Collections.IEnumerable
```